# C3 highlight on chart click and restore to initial state on clicking again

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, onclick, c3.js

I am trying to replicate the exact behavior on the click of any data-point in a C3 chart (refer this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/hx16Fb3qrEs8eFobvPeN)) without writing any custom event handler in onclick property. i.e I don't want to override onclick and don't want to use `d3.selectAll`.

Can I replicate the same behavior using data.selection properties (or any available properties) and overriding the css classes? somewhat similar approach taken in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnirbanBera/utzp8mwr/)

Comment: Please check the initial version. http://jsfiddle.net/utzp8mwr/2/   Going forward I will update